# SwipeRefreshLayout, when visibility == View.GONE, doesn't hide child view

Tags: android

I'm getting inconsistent behavior with SwipeRefreshLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE). Sometimes, my swipe refresh layouts hide the child view, but some times they don't. Since SwipeRefreshLayout subclasses ViewGroup, I'm expecting it to always hide the child view whenever it's visibility is .GONE, but that isn't happening.

Any insights are appreciated.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mySwipeRefreshLayout">

    <View
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Update: After spending the afternoon stripping everything out of the fragment, I confirmed that it's our setup that is causing the problem. Even so, it's still strange that setting the child view to VIEW.Gone works, but doing so to the swipe refresh layout doesn't hide the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel dumb, but my problem ended up being this: SwipeRefreshLayout doesn't hide while it is animating the refresh logo. You have to `setRefreshing(false)` in addition to `setVisibility(View.GONE)`. Even after `setRefreshing(false)`, there is an exit animation that happens after you use both of these methods.

Here's the solution I used to fix this. It not only handles calling `setRefreshing(false)` when you want to hide it, but it also sets the alpha to zero so it hides immediately without having to wait for the refresh animation to wind down.

```
public class HideableSwipeRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {

    public HideableSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setVisibility(int visibility) {

        if ((visibility == View.INVISIBLE) || (visibility == View.GONE)) {
            setAlpha(0);
            setRefreshing(false);
        } else {
            setAlpha(1);
        }

        super.setVisibility(visibility);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can confirm that this is not caused by your setup, you should report this as a bug, see https://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html.

As a workaround I recommend to wrap your layout into a `FrameLayout` and set the visibility on it instead of the `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

In your xml file provide id to SwipeRefreshLayout and view

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mySwipeRefreshLayout">

    <View
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

then use id of both in .java file and use their objects.

```
 if(swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()){
       view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);        
 }else{
       view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);    
 }
```

Comment: This is probably what I'll have to do, but I was hoping to get to the root of the problem rather than a workaround.

Comment: Have you used anything in .java file for this ?

Comment: If I understood your question, the only modifications I'm doing to the refresh layout in the fragment file is .setVisibility(), .setRefreshing(), and setOnRefreshListener(). 

Continuing to rip stuff out until I have a bare-bones fragment. As of now, the refresh layout is behaving the same.