# hide the content of fragment when progress bar is visible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-progressbar

My fragment contains lots of different views. Some views are already in the XML files like `imageview`,drawables, etc. and other views get filled with data after a successful response from Retrofit. The XML file also contains a toolbar and `progressbar`.

When data is coming from the server I want only toolbar and Progressbar to be shown and other content hidden. but the problem is I can't hide the whole view because it contains a toolbar and progress bar itself.

What should I do?

[image: Output I want]
[image: Output I am getting]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar...>

 <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swiperefresh_open_post"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_sec">

 <!-- this contains all Content I want to hide this -->
    <ScrollView...>

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


 <!-- this contains content which is fixed at the bottom I also want to hide this -->
<FrameLayout...>

<include layout="@layout/progressbar_item" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you share your xml code?

Comment: Yes please check it out @MuntasirAonik

Answer (score 0):

Just put the views to other places. If you use for example `FrameLayout`, you can have pretty flat structure, where `Toolbar` and `ProgressBar` are on the same hierarchy level as inner `FrameLayout` which contains the rest of the layout. So you can do something like this:

```xml
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp" >

             <!-- Put your layout here -->
    </FrameLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />
        
</FrameLayout>
```

and then just call

```kotlin
container.visibility = View.GONE
progressbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

or

```kotlin
container.visibility = View.VISIBLE
progressbar.visibility = View.GONE
```

Comment: XML file contains swipeRefreshLayout and if i put that in frameLayout I can't able to make it gone

Comment: Why not? See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289196/swiperefreshlayout-when-visibility-view-gone-doesnt-hide-child-view

Comment: If i put swiperefresh in FrameLayout and make FrameLayout gone all contain is still visible I just tried it

Comment: And also other problem is when data is coming from the server and some problem occurs like internet connection then I can't able to swipe in this case becuase the layout is gone and swipe is in that layout

Comment: Did you check the link from comment? If you call 'setRefreshing(false)` then you can make the `ScrollView` gone. Another thing is that you can try calling `scrollView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE` to check if it works

Comment: Yeah i saw that but I have to do it from both the layout scroll and framelayour from my xml file.